# gesturehandlerrootview was not found in the uimanager

Tags: react-native

This is the error status

ERROR  Invariant Violation:   requireNativeComponent:   "RNGestureHandlerRootView"was not found in the UIManager.

```
This error is located at:
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.tsx:17)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at DrawerView.tsx:317)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:85)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:46)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at DrawerView.tsx:316)
    in DrawerView (at createDrawerNavigator.tsx:126)
    in Unknown (at createDrawerNavigator.tsx:125)
    in DrawerNavigator (at App.js:159)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:430)
    in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
    in NavigationContainerInner (at App.js:158)
    in App (at safeTransportPolice/index.js:15)
    in Provider (at safeTransportPolice/index.js:14)
    in Container (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:43)
    in safeTransportPolice(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:60)
```

Comment: Have you installed `react-native-gesture-handler`? If yes, have you rebuild your app?

Comment: Yes, I have installed react-native-gesture-handler. also rebuild the app. same issue I am facing.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: @Md.AbulKhair I am facing the same issue, did you find any solution yet ?